# Installing Teamviewer Host on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: teamviewer

Trying to install Teamviewer Host as per instructions but run into a problem. The Ubuntu Software installer upon clicking the Install button seems to start the install process but then does nothing and the software is not installed. By does nothing the progress bar under the button displays for a few seconds and then goes away no request for auth nothing. If you try to run it again a default icon i.e. grey displays in the bar on the left with a progress bar imbedded in it but does nothing and can not be closed.

Comment: can you try to install from the command line and paste the output here? This will help find the problem. Let me know if  you don't know how to install, just run: `sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_FILE.DEB` replacing PACKAGE_FILE.DEB with the deb file you downloaded from the Teamviewer site

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer 12 installed fine on my 17.04. I do have firewall turned off. You might try that as Teamviewer wants to use its own ports or check your firewall ports OUTGOING CONNECTIONS.

> *However, in some situations, for example in a corporate environment with strict security policies, a firewall might be set up to block all unknown outbound connections, and in this case you will need to configure the firewall to allow TeamViewer to connect out through it.
>
> Blockquote

```
TCP/UDP Port 5938: TeamViewer prefers to make outbound TCP and UDP connections over port 5938 – this is the primary port it uses, and TeamViewer performs best using this port. Your firewall should allow this at a minimum.
TCP Port 443: If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938, it will next try to connect over TCP port 443.
Note: port 443 is also used by our custom modules which are created in the Management Console. If you’re deploying a custom module, eg. through Group Policy, then you need to ensure that port 443 is open on the computers to which you’re deploying. Port 443 is also used for a few other things, including TeamViewer update checks.


TCP Port 443: If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938, it will next try to connect over TCP port 443.

Note: port 443 is also used by our custom modules which are created in the Management Console. If you’re deploying a custom module, eg. through Group Policy, then you need to ensure that port 443 is open on the computers to which you’re deploying. Port 443 is also used for a few other things, including TeamViewer update checks.
TCP Port 80: If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938 or 443, then it will try on port TCP 80. The connection speed over this port is slower and less reliable than ports 5938 or 443, due to the additional overhead it uses, and there is no automatic reconnection if the connection is temporarily lost. For this reason port 80 is only used as a last resort.
TCP Port 80: If TeamViewer can’t connect over port 5938 or 443, then it will try on port TCP 80. The connection speed over this port is slower and less reliable than ports 5938 or 443, due to the additional overhead it uses, and there is no automatic reconnection if the connection is temporarily lost. For this reason port 80 is only used as a last resort.*
```